# "delivered effort" versus "deliberate effort"

Tags: expressions

If someone has written, "a delivered effort to do something," is it a typo where the intended word was "deliberate" or is it its own turn of phrase?

Answer (score 1):

Unless this occurs in the context of microeconomics, in which there is a distinction between contracted effort/work and delivered effort/work, I can't see how that is anything but a typo.

**Edit**: Adding a [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=D7P3X99RWvkC&pg=PA175&dq=%22contracted%20effort%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vKxNU8qoN8qMyQGA-oCICg&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22contracted%20effort%22&f=false) to a source that (sort of) helps elaborate. Essentially, "contracted effort" is what is agreed upon between an employee and employer and "delivered effort" is the resulting good-faith attempt to complete that work, regardless of the terms. These phrases are really limited to microeconomics or business admin discussions, so I would assume it's a typo or malaproprism.